# bootstrap font equals image

Tags: css

I started working with css and I'm having difficulty leaving the font equal to image, someone could give me a hint how to do this?

image: http://www.dlemes.com/jobs/utc.jpg

My partial layout: http://www.dlemes.com/jobs/

My CSS: http://pastebin.com/EDXm5itm

My HTML: http://pastebin.com/c5pKh5Nt

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS so we can help you.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to find name of the font used on this image?

Comment: I edited my post.
@Miljan Puzović I'm trying to leave the size, color same as the picture